# How to execute MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner for a .net solution which has multiple projects?

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.4

I have setup SonarQube with the following: `sonarqube-5.4`, `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0`, VS 2013 (target .NET Framework 4.5.1), SQL Server 2014 Express, Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-bit OS.

I am able to execute sonarqube runner for one .NET project (.csproj) successfully and generate the results.  Now I would like to execute `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0` for a .NET solution (.sln) which has many .csproj entries.

The folder structure is as below:

RootFolder has a .sln file, and each project (.csproj) is created in a separate folder inside the root folder.  Unit tests for each project are also created in a separate folder inside the root folder. For example:

```
RootFolder -> Project.sln
RootFolder -> ProjectABCFolder -> ProjectABC.csproj
RootFolder -> ProjectABCTestsFolder -> ProjectABCTests.csproj
RootFolder -> ProjectXYZFolder -> ProjectXYZ.csproj
RootFolder -> ProjectXYZTestsFolder -> ProjectXYZTests.csproj
```

Can you help me on the following ?

1. How to execute the .sln file - what the required entries / settings to be made ?
2. How to skip the unit test projects ?
3. How to include the unit test projects ?
4. How to execute the VS Code Analysis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all of this is covered here exception for the unit test exclusion.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+the+Command+Line

To run for the whole solution you should be able to just run the following from your RootFolder:

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin // Other args
msbuild /t:Rebuild Project.sln
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

As for your unit test questions. Most people choose not to include the test code in the project. This is done via the regex in the sonarqube UI: Administration->Scanner for MSBuild. Changing this regex to something that doesn't match for your test projects will cause them to be included.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did the same. I have added the regex "/.Tests/" to exclude the test projects (ProjectABC.Tests.csproj, ProjectXYZ.Tests.csproj etc.) But still the test projects are also being evaluated and then the analysis fails. How to exclude test projects from execution ?

Comment: The default regex should be excluding tests with the name you specified. Change it back to the default and post a link to the runner output if there is nothing proprietary in it.